# firebase deploy problems-nodeJS version

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-cli

when I want to deploy my project with firebase, I encountered the nodeJS version problem and it troubled me for many days.
when I apply the command "firebase deploy --only functions", then it reminds me that:

```
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix functions install
audited 5522 packages in 8.196s
found 11 vulnerabilities (2 low, 5 moderate, 4 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

Error: The module 
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 48. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:681:18)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> 
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)

Having trouble? Try firebase deploy --help
```

my node version is v8.11.3
my npm version is 6.2.0

Anyone knows how to solve it?? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I tried all the solution I can find like "npm update" "npm install", but they all don't work. Also, I tried many other versions of nodejs but no one can solve this problem.

Comment: Try `npm rebuild`, or barring that, `rm -rf node_modules` in your functions directory and run `npm install` again.

Comment: Don't show images of errors and code.  Copy the text into a the question itself so it's easy to read and search.

Comment: I tried "npm rebuild" and "rm -rf node_modules", also "npm install". They all don't work. Is there other reason which can cause this problem??

Answer (score 0):

Was running into the same issues.  Updated my Node JS version to v8.16.0, then within my Functions / package.json I added the nodeJS engine version:

```
 "engines": { "node": "8" },
```

I am now able to deploy my functions.

Found the answer here:  https://howtofirebase.com/cloud-functions-migrating-to-node-8-9640731a8acc